# how to see the call tree in eclipse when in debug mode?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to see the call tree (hierarchie) in Eclipse debug mode ?

I mean I set a breakpoint in a method which was called from another classes method. How can I figure out which method has called my method method in which I have set the breakpoint.

Comment: The term you're looking for is *call stack*. It should be visible in the Debug perspective.

Comment: You can use call heirarchy to check the method call...to see break points use breakpoint view in eclipse...its better if you use debug mode

Comment: When your breakpoint hits, Eclipse will ask if you want to switch to the `Debug` *Perspective*. Say "Yes", because that perspective has all the nice views that are relevant when debugging, including the `Debug` *View* that you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your code is suspended on a breakpoint the call stack is shown in the 'Debug' view:

[image: Call stack]

In this example I have a breakpoint in the `LifeCycle.postContextCreate` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I see it now. Got only problems in the Android view. I had to remove the perspective and added it again. Seems to be a bug.

Comment: Reset helped me too.